# Creating a WordPress 301 Redirect Function To redirect each page on old domain to the same page on a new domain

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect, http-status-code-301

If I don't have permissions from the host to create or write to an .htaccess file what would be the way to 301 redirect each page on an old WordPress website Domain to a corresponding Page on a new WordPress website domain. I don't want to simply redirect the old domain to the new domain, but want to redirect each page /Post etc. I was thinking it might be possible to write a function in the functions.php for to accomplish this am looking for some pointers to start.

Comment: a [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) is what you need. fyi, if your new web hosting company does not allow you to write to htaccess, you may have problems if you have pretty permalinks. i personally would get a new web host provider asap.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you clarify what access you do have?  Do you/would you still have access to your old domain's WP Dashboard? And can WordPress still write to it?

If so, redirection plugins (http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/redirect) might be of some help?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the dashboard/wp-admin on the old domain, then you can use the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin to achieve this.